# ViewSonic Monitor and Nvidia Graphics Card: Overscan

Tags: nvidia, xorg, resolution

I am struggeling now for almost half a year with my graphic-configuration (
**ViewSonic VX2835wm, nvidia GeForce  GTS 450**). On a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 with the proprietary **nvidia driver Version 331.38** (the nouveau driver doesn't serve any better) the edges of my screen are cut (overscan).

When I used Ubuntu 12.04 I could fix this problem. Back then I found out that the monitor sends **bad EDID** information. As a result wrong values were used for the configuration (Vertical Sync, Horizontal Refresh).

However, my **old xorg.conf** couldn't solve the issues under Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to implement it in many variations, but nothing really worked. Here is the old xorg.conf that fixed the problem under Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier  "gfgts450"
Driver      "nvidia"
Option      "NoLogo"    "True"
Screen      0
Option "ModeValidation" "DFP-1: NoMaxPClkCheck"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "vx2835wm"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 85.0
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1200"
    Modeline    "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
    Option      "ExactModeTimingsDVI"   "TRUE"
    Gamma       1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Device      "gfgts450"
    Monitor     "vx2835wm"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option      "TwinView"  "0"
    Option      "metamodes" "1920x1200 +0+0"
    Option      "UseEDID"   "FALSE"
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth       24
                Modes "1920x1200"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

My current xorg.conf which proides the overscan issue looks like this:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "ViewSonic VX2835wm"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 85.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTS 450"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1200_60 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Can someone identify the specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Option      "UseEDID"   "False"` and `Modes "1920x1200"`

to same sections of the new file.

Also

```
    HorizSync       24.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 85.0
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1200"
    Modeline    "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
    Option      "ExactModeTimingsDVI"   "TRUE"
```

in "Monitor" section may be useful.

But do not create duplicate lines. E.g. replace `HorizSync 30.0 - 82.0` with `HorizSync       24.0 - 82.0`